# Extract Elements From a String Using Regular Expressions

Tags: r

I have the following string:

`x <- "DevicePool1/Device1/Measurements/20210910231005/event.csv"`

how can I retrieve `Device1` out of this string in `R` ?

Comment: What is is that you want?  The exact string Device1?  The second component of the path?

Comment: yes the second component of the path "Device1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression

```
> gsub(".*/(.*?)/.*","\\1",x)
[1] "Device1"
```

`.*` means any character appearing 0 or more times and
`/(.*?)/`is your pattern

Answer (score 3):

Try any of these. The first 4 also work if x is a character vector such that each element stores a path, e.g. `x <- c(x, x)`. No packages are used.

```
read.table(text = x, sep = "/", fill = TRUE)[[2]]

sub(".*?/(.*?)/.*", "\\1", x)

gsub("^.*?/|/.*", "", x, perl = TRUE)

sapply(strsplit(x, "/"), `[`, 2)

scan(text = x, sep = "/", what = "", quiet = TRUE)[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one using `regexpr` and `regmatches` with look behind for `/` using `(?<=/)` and look ahead for `/` using `(?=/)` and get the non greedy match in between with `.*?` or everything but not `/` using `[^/]*`.

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=/).*?(?=/)", x, perl=TRUE))
#regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=/)[^/]*(?=/)", x, perl=TRUE)) #Alternative
#[1] "Device1"
```

Or using `[^/]*` in `sub`

```
sub("[^/]*/([^/]*)/.*", "\\1", x)
#sub("/.*", "", sub("[^/]*/", "", x)) #Alternative
#gsub("^[^/]*/|/.*", "", x) #Alternative
#[1] "Device1
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work in your case from stringr package

```
x <- "DevicePool1/Device1/Measurements/20210910231005/event.csv"
unlist(str_split(x, "/"))[2]
```